# 12 V vehicle power distribution question

Tags: batteries, current, dc-dc-converter

I am trying to find a solution where I need to add a connection to power a device that is expected to draw 50 A. The car has a DC-DC converter which has a current limit of 160 A which is also used to charge the 12 V battery.

With the existing loads connected to this converter, they draw a total of 158 A from the DC-DC converter so I am not able to add this extra 50 A load directly to the converter.

I am thinking of getting power to this new load straight from the 12 V battery, but I am not sure if this load will drain the 12 V battery at a rate faster than the charging rate of the battery from the DC-DC converter.

Is it a possible solution? If not, can you explain the reason?

Comment: This doesn't sound like a normal vehicle.  Is it electric?

Comment: You might tell some more details about the battery specification (capacity, type), the load type (motor, heater, pump,... ), how long the load should be active in a given time frame and what other loads consume current at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

If the DC/DC converter is charging the battery, and you connect a 50A load to the battery, then the DC/DC converter will still end up powering the 50A load.
You can't charge and discharge a battery at the same time.

If the converter then shuts down because it's overloaded, then the battery will end up powering everything.